# Cannot access environment variable in desired file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to access environment variables in my Display.js, I have created a .env file in the root of my project, however, process.env is not logging my env variable.

.env inside of root folder of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaKMQ.png

Display.js (located in same folder as .env):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJG80.png

Image of my folders:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlAsZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.env` must be located of project root directory

Comment: Still not working for some reason...